# writing to a csv file in java based on some condition

Tags: java, list, csv, filereader

I am fetching the data by reading from a csv file and storing it as List<List<String<>> "data". While trying to write that data to another csv file I need to Check a condition whether id in this "rowdata" matches with id column of another csv file or not. Please help in how to check this condition.

The condition is data.id=value.id;// value is data from another csv in the form List<List<String<>> value

```
public void writeRecords(List<List<String>> data) throws IOException {
    
    FileWriter csvWriter1 = new FileWriter(OUTPUT_PATH);
    Cable c1=new Cable();
    List<List<String>> value=c1.readRecords();

    for (List<String> rowData : data) {
                csvWriter1.append(String.join(",", rowData));
                csvWriter1.append("\n");
    }
    csvWriter1.flush();
    csvWriter1.close();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would not suggest you to operate with data structure like that `List<List<String<>> "data"`.However, assumed all your lists are sorted and you don't care about code complexity level - in your situation you can do smth like that to compare data from your two lists:

```
for (int i =0; i<value.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<value.get(i).size(); j++) {
            if(value.get(i).get(j)==data.get(i).get(j));
            //write data to another csv
        }
    }
```